# How to configure Visual Studio 2010 to stop my program when a XamlParseException is thrown?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, exception

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0. When I debug my program, it doesn't shows me the XamlParseException, but when I install my program and run it, the exception is thrown and my program stops working. How do I configure VS10 to show me the XamlParseException? How do I debug this exception?

Comment: Attach your debugger (tools/attach to process).

Comment: Are you sure your installed program is 100% identical to the version your are debugging in VS?

Comment: No it's not identical. For one, the location is different. And possibly not all projects assets are installed.

Comment: At least, the code is identical. I'm refreshing my solution and creating a new installer.

Comment: Check line number in the exception, it already reveals where in stack trace the error occured. probably it cannot find an XML file or something.

Comment: Do you have the exception message from the System Event Viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I configure VS10 to show me the XamlParseException?

This question has already been answered but unfortunately using the solution provided will not solve your problem. Let me try to explain why:

In the **Debug** -> **Exceptions** dialog box you can turn on **Break when an exception is** either **Thrown** or **User-unhandled** and in this case you want to do this for `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`. Normally, you will have **User-unhandled** checked. The setting only applies when your are running your application in the Visual Studio debugger, and when the setting is turned on the debugger will break in the code when the exception is thrown if there is not try-catch handler to catch the exception. This is very useful because you can inspect variables etc. at the point in your code when the error is discovered.

If you have a try-catch handler for your exception you might still want the debugger to break when the exception is thrown. In that case you have to check the **Thrown** check box for that to happen. This can be useful if you want to troubleshoot why and where a particular exception is thrown in an application that has exception handling (which most applications should have).

However, in your case you do not have exception handling for `XamlParseException` as you your *"program stops working"* and throws an `XamlParseException`. Running your application in the debugger should produce the same unhandled exception but it does not.

So you should change your question from "how do I configure the debugger to break when an exception is thrown?" to "why is `XamlParseException` thrown in my production environment and not when running in the debugger?"

Unfortunately, I do not have a good answer for the second question. For starters, getting more details about the exception would be useful as it will point to some XAML that fails to load. It should point to a XAML source file and position and may also have an inner exception with further information.

However, as the XAML is loaded by the runtime and not directly by your code it might be difficult to figure out where to place the catch handler for the `XamlParseException`. You might try the [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) but that is not available on all platforms using XAML (you have not specified if you are using WPF, Silverlight etc.)

Comment: I followed your suggestions and solved my problems. Now my errors are shown up when I debug my program. Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio menu you have `Debug->Exceptions`

Here you can configure the exceptions you want your debugger to stop at.

Verify that `Common Language Runtime Exception` is checked for `Thrown` column

Comment: @verdosrobert Do you know what the columns "Thrown" and "User-unhandled" mean?

Comment: While that *does* answer the question "how to configure VS... etc", it won't solve the *actual* problem if the exception is never thrown in the debugging environment.

Comment: Thrown is before the exception reaches any catch
While User-unhandled is thrown only when there is no catch anywhere in the flow where that exceptions happend

Answer (score 1):

verdesrobert and blacai both answers the question you ask in the title, **but that won't help you** if as you say the code is the same. Normally your code would have crashed on the same exception in your debugging environment too, regardless of exception settings.

So clearly there's some kind of difference between your debugging environment and the production environment that causes this. What will help you is to narrow down these differences. For starters, **you should try and log the exception's stack trace** when it occurs in your deployed application, **as well as the XAML code** you are trying to parse.

This should give you a clue on how to reproduce the scenario in your environment and solve the problem once and for all. You can also log anything else that may be of interest: security context, runtime version, OS version, etc, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Check you have the following option selected.

[image]